# Jenkins Build Failure "Could not find or load main class –Xmx512m:

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins.  I created the new job using Maven project.  After the configuration I select the build.  It got failed and this is the Error message.  Does anyone know in what case this error occurs?

```
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Test
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 52863
[TestForm] $ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java –Xmx512m –XX:MaxPermSize=128m -cp /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/MavenTest/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/MavenTest/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/MavenTest /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.14.jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar 52863
Error: Could not find or load main class –Xmx512m
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Test/Users/xyz/eclipse-workspace/TestForm/pom.xml
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1770)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.properties.PomPropertiesFinder.findProperties(PomPropertiesFinder.java:50)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoExtractor.extract(MavenInfoExtractor.java:58)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoEnvironment.tearDown(MavenInfoEnvironment.java:42)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:908)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: /Users/xyz/eclipse-workspace/TestForm/test-output/testng-results.xml 
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: I'd recommend not using the Maven project type - see [this blog post](https://javaadventure.blogspot.com/2013/11/jenkins-maven-job-type-considered-evil.html). It is also going to be difficult for anybody to help you without an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why can I read something about `eclipse-workspace` in your Jenkins? `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Test/Users/xyz/eclipse-workspace/TestForm/pom.xml`

Comment: @khmarbaise I gave the pom path which is in the eclipse-workspace

Comment: The eclipse workspace does not necessarily contain the source code...

Comment: @khmarbaise I created Maven project using Eclipse Maven (Download Maven from Eclipse market place).  So when when I create the project it automatically goes under the eclipse-workplace folder. When I configure Jenkins I choose clean installed and gave the pom path as `/Users/xyz/eclipse-workspace/TestForm/pom.xml`.  Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: But based on the message there is missing something ?

Comment: @khmarbaise copy and paste whole console output.  Also, please see the above message.  I edited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165171/discussion-between-user3174886-and-khmarbaise).

Comment: Looks like wrong symbol is used instead of hyphen in "–Xmx512m" and in "–XX:MaxPermSize=128m" in `[TestForm] $ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java –Xmx512m –XX:MaxPermSize=128m -cp ...`

Comment: @Ivan Is there anyway I can edit it?

Comment: @user3174886 try to check `Jenkins global configuration page (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System) and look for the Maven Project Configuration` or `Select "Advanced" in the node Configure page:
Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > New Node ( or select existing node) > Configure > Advanced `. Unfortunately I haven't worked with Jenkins so cannot provide exact instructions where to look.